# Closed form of $\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{k}{n}\left(-1\right)^k$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Consider the following binomial summation:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{k}{n}\left(-1\right)^k$$

For $m\ge n\ge0$ and $m,n \in \mathbb N$

---

This is indeed the alternating sign [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{k}{n}\left(-1\right)^k=\sum_{k=n}^{m}\binom{k}{k-n}\left(-1\right)^k=\left(-1\right)^{-n}\sum_{k=n}^{m}\binom{-n-1}{k-n}$$

Setting $k-n \mapsto k$ follows:

$$=\left(-1\right)^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{m-n}\binom{-n-1}{k}$$

I also tried the classical method:

$$S_{n}:=\sum_{k=n}^{m}\binom{k}{n}\left(-1\right)^k=\sum_{k=n}^{m}\binom{k+1}{n+1}\left(-1\right)^k-\sum_{k=n}^{m}\binom{k}{n+1}\left(-1\right)^k$$

Setting $k+1 \mapsto k$ yields:

$$=-\sum_{k=n+1}^{m+1}\binom{k}{n+1}\left(-1\right)^k-\sum_{k=n}^{m}\binom{k}{n+1}\left(-1\right)^k$$
$$=-\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}\binom{k}{n+1}\left(-1\right)^k-\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}\binom{k}{n+1}\left(-1\right)^k+\binom{m}{n}\left(-1\right)^m=-2S_{n+1}+\binom{m}{n}\left(-1\right)^m$$

Using this , a recurrence relation can be derived:

$$S_{n+1}=\frac{\binom{m}{n}\left(-1\right)^m-S_n}{2}$$

But it's not what I want!

So how we can find a closed form for alternating sign Hockey-stick identity?

---

Comment: What are you looking for in (II)? Isn't the right hand side already a closed form by most standards?

Comment: Also, I highly recommend posting different problems in different threads when the only relation is "binomial sum looking for closed form".

Comment: @darijgrinberg, I edited that, indeed in the second case I did not want a closed form (I just don't not know how to continue), and thanks I will do that.

Comment: I doubt there's a closed form, unless you're willing to consider hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Just trying some cases, $s(n,m)$ appears to be the expansion of $1/((1-x)(1+x)^{n+1})$ (from OEIS for $n=3,4$)